# SQL/BigQuery: GroupBy If List Contains Common Element

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I would like to perform a query in SQL that will do a groupby if a list contains a common element. For example:

```
| ID       | Groups         | Amount |
| -------- | -------------- | -------|
| 1        |[A,B]           | 5      |
| 2        |[A,C,D]         | 10     |
| 3        |[C,B]           | 20     |
```

So that if I do a GROUP BY on the GROUPS, it will do:

```
|Groups | AVG(Amount)|
|------ | -----------|
|A      | 7.5        |
|B      | 12.5       |
|C      | 15         |
|D      | 10.        |
```

The list lengths are variable.

A few ideas I had are one-hot encoding (expanding along the columns), or duplicate the rows by flattening or using UNNEST, but am not sure the best way to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to "flatten" an array.

Consider below query:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS
SELECT 1 ID, ['A','B'] `Groups`, 5 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 2, ['A','C','D'], 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, ['C','B'], 20;

SELECT g AS `Groups`, AVG(Amount) AS avg_amount 
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST(`Groups`) g
 GROUP BY 1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your question you did not mention about column that you want group but you are looking for ARRAY_AGG() function.

For example:

```
WITH vals AS
  (
    SELECT 1 x, 'a' y UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 x, 'b' y UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 x, 'a' y UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 x, 'c' y
  )
SELECT x, ARRAY_AGG(y) as array_agg
FROM vals
GROUP BY x;

+---------------+
| x | array_agg |
+---------------+
| 1 | [a, b]    |
| 2 | [a, c]    |
+---------------+
```

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg)

Comment: Hi charizard, thank you for responding. I believe in my question I mentioned the column that I wanted to group; I wanted to do a GROUP BY with GROUPS, and aggregate over the average of AMOUNT. I'm not trying to create an array with GROUP BY using ARRAY_AGG(), I'm trying to "flatten" an array. Does that clear things up?